# Como pego parâmetros de uma requisição PUT?

Tags: php, web-service, rest, http-request, http-métodos

Estou começando a estudar Web Service e criei um exemplo de uma API em REST. Estou passando parâmetros via PUT para a API e pegando com o `parse_str` no PHP mas o que retorna para mim é algo completamente diferente...

Como faço para pegar os parâmetros de forma correta para consumir minha API?

Meu código:

```
case "PUT":
        echo "PUT<br /><br />";

        echo "Inputs:<br/>";
        parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$put_vars);

        echo "<br/>JSON:<br/>";
        echo json_encode($put_vars);

        echo "<br/><br/>Array comum:<br/>";
        print_r($put_vars);
        break;
```

Print da resposta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Formulário que você envia está como multipart/form-data?

Comment: Na verdade estou usando Postman para fazer os testes...

Comment: No Postman têm a opção de fazer com multipart/form-data ou envia a requisição como raw. É essa última que você está utilizando?

Comment: Não, verifiquei aqui e está marcada a opção form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode utilizar `multipart/form-data` para enviar `PUT` ou `DELETE`
o Postman têm uma opção para enviar requisições como raw (crua), utilize desta forma que deve funcionar

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.